# No me muestra la imagen en mi Pagina Web

Tags: html5, django

Buenas,llevo poco tiempo aprendiendo django, mi problema surje cuando intento cargar la imagen asociada a un objeto de la base de datos.

```
{% extends 'index.html' %}
{% block titulo %}
Jugadores
{% endblock %}
{% block menu%}
{% if jugadores %}

<div class='col-sm-6'>
<hr>
{% load static %}
{% for jugador in jugadores %}   
<img src="{% static "jugador.imagen" %}">       
<p><h2>Nombre:{{ jugador.nombre }}</h2></p>
<p><h3>Edad:{{ jugador.edad }}</h3></p>
<p><h3>Posicion:{{ jugador.posicion }}</h3></p>

{% endfor %}
{% else %}
<p><h2>No hay jugadores</h2></p>
{% endif %}
</div>

<hr>
{% endblock %}
{% block header %}
{% endblock %}
```

Mi pagina web, queda así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi problema es que, al introducir mi imagen en la base datos, me genera un directorio static paralelo donde tengo mi proyecto y al llamar a esa imagen en mis templates no encuentra dicha imagen

Comment: Hora Rafael, bienvenido. Por favor, sustituye la imagen del codigo por texto para que sea mas legible y poder copiar y pegar. Un saludo^^

Comment: Por favor, [edita](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/45886/edit) tu pregunta, no uses los comentarios

Comment: Ya lo he modificado, disculpar el lio, pero soy nuevo en el foro :(

Comment: No pasa nada. pero para que no pasen cosas asi, visita el [Tour](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)  y el [Centro de ayuda](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help). :D

Answer (score 1):

Has verificado la ruta de la imagen en el código fuente resultante de la web (en la visualización del navegador). Si en la base de datos tienes la imagen entera, no puedes mostrarla así, a no ser que la conviertas a base-64 (mira [ésto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207190/embedding-base64-images)). Si en la base de datos sólo tienes el nombre de la imagen, verifica que la ruta está completa en el src="", de lo contrario buscará la imagen en el directorio actual.

Otra anotación: abres el FOR dentro del DIV y lo cierras fuera, lo cual rompe el código de la web, creando tags abiertos o incompletos.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, el problema es que la base de datos me guarda mis archivos media en un directorio diferente a donde tengo mi carpeta static.

Answer (score 0):

que tal.

No hace falta cargar el static para mostrar una imagen de un objeto que creaste en el template

Lo primero que debes asegurarte es que en tu settings tengas correctamente configuradas el directorio para almacenar los archivos media y la url para accederles

Ubica en el settings.py lo siguiente
`MEDIA_ROOT`
`MEDIA_URL`

Luego en tu modelo asegurate de indicar en el campo, donde lo almacenarias

`imagen = models.ImageField(upload_to='path/to/dir/', blank=True, null=True)`

Si todo esto esta correcto y se están almacenando las imagenes correctamente, bastaría con que en tu template coloques

`<img src="/media/{{jugador.imagen}}" />`

Saludos y espero mi respuesta te sea de utilidad